# convert image gray scale python error

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, scipy, python-imaging-library

I'm working on a 3D scanner;  my first step is to convert image to gray scale:

```
 from PIL import *
 import scipy
 import scipy.ndimage as ndimage
 import scipy.ndimage.filters as filters
 from numpy import *
 from pylab import *
 import cv2

 cv2.namedWindow("Image")

 image = cv2.imread('/home/mehdi/Bureau/002.jpg')
 im = scipy.misc.imread(image,flatten=1)
 cv2.imshow("Image",im)
 cv2.waitKey(0)
 cv2.destroyALLWindows()
```

and this is the error message I get:

```
   `opengl support available 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "mehdi01.py", line 12, in <module>
       im = scipy.misc.imread(image,flatten=1)
       File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scip/misc
          /pilutil.py", line 97, in imread
         im = Image.open(name)
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py",
        line 1959,  in open
         prefix = fp.read(16)
          AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'read'
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the error message you got, you can reach your goal by setting the flag `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` for `cv2.imread()`. To type less, you can write `0` instead of `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE`.

Note also that you have a typo in `cv2.destroyALLWindows()`. Change it to `cv2.destroyAllWindows()` instead

So your code becomes simply:

```
from numpy import *
import cv2

cv2.namedWindow("Image")
im = cv2.imread('/home/mehdi/Bureau/002.jpg',0)
cv2.imshow("Image",im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Or:

```
from numpy import *
import cv2

cv2.namedWindow("Image")
im = cv2.imread('/home/mehdi/Bureau/002.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
cv2.imshow("Image",im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: As a reader of code, I'd hugely prefer `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` over the magic constant `0`, which doesn't give any clue what's happening.